# How to increase the red block on the right side?

Tags: css, html

So, I attached 2 images, which show that i want to do. Please,can anybody advice me ?
P.S. I have tried to use maring-right, but it didn't work.

[It's my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UYDg.png)

[And i should to make topnav like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw28t.png)

```css
.topnav {
    width:750px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Verdana,"Sans-serif",Helvetica,Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Стиль ссылок навигации */
.topnav a {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:3px;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Изменение цвета при наведении */
.topnav a:hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
   <nav>
    <div class="topnav"> <!--Верхнее меню -->
  <a href="#top">Новости</a>
  <a href="#top">О Суде</a>
  <a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the width of `.topnav` to 100% or remove it altogether, since `div` fill out all horizontal space by default. If you want full width and a white space to the left, use the margin or margin-left property.

https://jsfiddle.net/nb5yh30z/1/

Comment: Made it, but now horizontal space use all part of header(include left stide)

https://imgur.com/a/X1i8W

Comment: Then use `margin-left`. Or padding-left. There are countless ways of formatting a document

Answer (score 0):

Using float: right; is the correct way.

```
.topnav {
    float:right;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Verdana,"Sans-serif",Helvetica,Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align:center;
}
```